# assign string and show in textfield

Tags: ios, swift

I have 2 views.
First view is type 'ISBN' barcode,
But for auto-filling the ISBN by camera,
I add button.
So second view is shown in modal when user touch the button
when 'ISBN' is detected,
the secondview is dismissed and 
and in the first view,
the textfield is filled with the detected 'ISBN' in Second View.

I usually pass data and show result by using `UILabel`.
but now I get error like below.

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

class for First view is UploadMain;

```
import UIKit


class UploadMain: UIViewController {


var ISBNstring: String = ""


@IBOutlet weak var ISBN: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
}

@IBAction func scanBarcode(sender: AnyObject) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("scanModal", sender: self)
}
}
```

second is ScanView;

```
class ScanView : UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {

let session         : AVCaptureSession = AVCaptureSession()
var previewLayer    : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
var detectionString : String!

*****

if let UploadVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("UploadMain") as? UploadMain {
UploadVC.ISBNstring = self.detectionString!
UploadVC.ISBN.text! = UploadVC.ISBNstring   // maybe error here                
}
```

Comment: there is absolutely no reason for a *"maybe error here"* - Xcode tells you **exactly** where the error occurs. But you should drop the `!` in that line anyway.

Comment: ISBN.text! = ISBNstring       // in viewDidLoad() of UploadMain

Comment: UploadVC.ISBN.text! = UploadVC.ISBNstring  // remove from ScanView

Comment: but UploadVC is shown in modal way. where did i add it UploadVC.ISBN.text! = UploadVC.ISBNstring in the UploadMain?

Comment: but you know, after dismissing the modal view , viewDidLoad() is not reloaded in the UploadMain

Answer (score 0):

```
if let UploadVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("UploadMain") as? UploadMain {
UploadVC.ISBNstring = self.detectionString!
UploadVC.ISBN.text! = UploadVC.ISBNstring
```

This is not the right way to do it .
You should be using delegates to propogate the changes . Using NSUserDefault is not the right thing here, though it is the easy soulution .

Comment: i already tried similar way. in the second view(show in modal way from first view)    in second view,,  if let UploadVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("UploadMain") as? UploadMain {
UploadVC.ISBNstring = self.detectionString!   and in the viewDidLoad()of UploadMain(firstView) UploadVC.ISBN.text! = UploadVC.ISBNstring

Comment: but you know, after dismissing the modal view , viewDidLoad() is not reloaded in the first view

Comment: then try it in viewWillAppear() , it will be called each time

Comment: override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        ISBN.text! = ISBNstring
     } i coded like this, its no error but cant see the barcode

Comment: You should be using delegates to propogate the changes

Comment: can you explain more detail? i can not understand.... im not familiar with delegates yet..

Comment: So there is some even happens in ScanView class and it should be reflected in UploadVC , so use delegates for call back , when ever that change will happen in that class it will be automatically reflected in your other class , read more about delegates here http://useyourloaf.com/blog/quick-guide-to-swift-delegates/

Answer (score 0):

second is ScanView add this dismissed view

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject( self.detectionString!, forKey: "ISBNtxt")
```

class for First view is UploadMain

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
{
     if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("ISBNtxt")) != nil
     {
          ISBN.text! = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("ISBNtxt") as! String
     }
}
```

Comment: thanks it works, but is there other way that does not use NSUserDefault?